# Can you integrate 2 or more SF Users in the same ORG with different MIDs?

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, marketing-cloud-connect, sfmc-business-unit

If I want to integrate a lot of MIDs from different Enterprise Accounts, can I create more than 1 integrated user in the same SF ORG to be able to integrate this different MIDs?

If it not possible, how can I integrate multiple BUs (around 10) with the same Integrated User?

I read in the documentation, it is just available up to 5 BUs

Note, all of this without Multi-org

Answer (score 0):

Ok If I read it correct

1. you have 10 MC BUs in 10 different Enterprise accounts(not 10BU in 1 Account)
2. you have 1 SF Org
3. you want to Connect 10 of those BUs with 1 SF org without using multi org Connector

Based on above scenarios , you would have 10 different users in 10 different enterprise MC accounts and you can connect with 10 different integrated users in the same 1 Org(as per your first question) but you can’t map multiple Marketing Cloud users in one enterprise account to the same Sales or Service Cloud user.

please refer [multi Org Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_account_and_user_configuration.htm&type=5) for details

Comment: Thanks Pardeep! but the question is more: Can you have 2 or 3 or more SF Users in the same ORG to connect more BUs? How many SF User to integrate can you have per ORG? Thanks!

Comment: @Mrquestion, One SF Org will have One Integration User per SFMC Connection.